# PostgreSQL upgrade from 11.22 to 12.17 - facing sql_identifier issue

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services

Error message: Your installation contains the "sql_identifier" data type in user tables and/or indexes.  The on-disk format for this data type has changed, so this cluster cannot currently be upgraded.  You can remove the problem tables or change the data type to "name" and restart the upgrade.
A list of the problem columns is in the file: tables_using_sql_identifier.txt

Question 1: How to view - tables_using_sql_identifier.txt in AWS?

Question 2: We updated data type from SQL_Identifier to Character in user tables. We also see there are several tables / columns from Information_Schema having SQL_Identifier data types but unable to change them. is there a solution or workaround to address this issue

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Read this [Information Schema Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/infoschema-datatypes.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can query `information_schema.columns` to find all instances where you used `sql_identifier` in user-defined tables.

Don't convert them to `char`, because that is a data type that you should avoid (see the PostgreSQL documentation). Convert the cokumns to `text` with

```
ALTER TABLE tab ALTER col TYPE text;
```

But leave the views in `information_schema` alone. They are no problem for the upgrade, and you should never modify system objects.

As an aside: don't upgrade to v12, which is only months from going out of support. Upgrade to at least v16.

Comment: Thank you Laurenz for the quick response. I have changed data type to text in user tables. i see there are many 'VIEWS' in information_schema has data type as 'sql_identifier' for example:
_pg_foreign_data_wrappers
_pg_foreign_servers
_pg_foreign_tables
_pg_user_mappings
administrable_role_authorizations
applicable_roles
attributes

we tried to upgrade with version 12 but still getting same error. we will have to check with upgrading directly to version 16. I will update on Monday how it goes.

Comment: You won't get any errors about the `information_schema`, unless you did strange and forbidden things to it.

Comment: Hi Laurenz Albe, successfully upgraded to 16.10. Big Thank to you and Stack Overflow team. First we changed data type from sql_identifier to 'name' across all user tables. second we upgraded to version 14.10, performed tests that includes excel connectors and upgraded to 16.10. need to test excel connectors with latest ODBC connector. Any suggestions / recommendations on using excel connectors with RDS version 16.10 will be highly helpful. Our goal is to avoid excel connectors in the first place though.